# How to use pox. Core and pox. Lib

Tags: python, mininet, sdn, pox

Showing that there ia no module named pox. Core and pox. Lib even after installing pox

I tried to implement pox Multi-level hierarchical controller placement in sdn

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.